# Nonmeasureable subset of ${\mathbb{R}}^2$ such that no three points are collinear?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I'm exploring the properties of sets in the plane that do not contain a set of three collinear points.  In particular, I'm interested in the "largest" they can be.

Things I know so far:

Assuming the axiom of choice, one can use Zorn's lemma to show that there are maximal subsets of ${\mathbb{R}}^2$ with this property.

A circle is an easy example of such a set that is uncountable.

If a Lebesgue measurable set $S \subseteq {\mathbb{R}}^2$ has this property, then it contains at most two points on any vertical line.  So the integral of $\chi_S$ in the $y$-direction is 0, and by Tonelli's theorem $m(S) = 0$.  But this argument doesn't work if $S$ is nonmeasurable.

So the question arises:  Is there such a set that is Lebesgue nonmeasurable?  (Since there are models of ZF in which every subset of ${\mathbb{R}}$ is Lebesgue measurable, this might actually depend on the choice of set theory axioms.)

edit:  One line of thought I am pursuing is thinking of Lebesgue nonmeasurable sets as sets with positive outer measure.  Also, one can generalize the question to consider subsets of ${\mathbb{R}}^n$ that do not contain a set of 3 collinear points, or perhaps $n+1$ co-hyperplanar points.  For these questions the case ${\mathbb{R}}^1$ is trivial, and maybe there's something different about dimensions higher than 2 à la Banach-Tarski.

Comment: Yes, there are such nonmeasurable sets. Such a set was constructed by Sierpinski using the axiom of choice and transfinite induction (I will look te paper up later). The idea is to construct the set in such a way that it intersects every compact subset of positive measure in the plane. By regularity it must then have positive measure **if it is measurable**, but your argument shows that it must have measure zero. Hence it is nonmeasurable.

Comment: @PhoemueX Can you find this paper?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about that. The paper is linked in my answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1030183/one-question-about-the-fubinis-theorem. But the paper is in french. A similar construction is given in this answer http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1123897/sets-are-measurable.

Answer (score -2):

I didnt understand many of the things written by you, like why the integral of $\chi_S = 0$. Anyways, as far as non-measurable set of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with no three points collinear is concerned, consider this:

Let $N$ be a non-measurable set of $[0,1)$. Let $\phi:[0,1)\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $\phi(t) = (\cos(2\pi t), \sin(2\pi t))$, then $\phi(N)$ is non-measurable too. Also no three points of $\phi(N)$ are collinear. See if this example helps you.

Comment: If we are talking about Lebesgue measurability instead of Borel measurability, your example does not work, since your set clearly is a Lebesgue null set.

Comment: (Plane) Lebesgue measure of a circle is 0. Moreover, *any* subset of a measure-0 set is Lebesgue measurable, since both its outer and inner (Borel) measures are 0. Knowledge of trivial properties of the Lebesgue measure might help your PhD pursuits.