# "+"-Sets are measurable.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

$A$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ that for every $(x,y) \in A$ there is a $\delta >0$ that $(x-\delta , x+\delta) \times \{y\}$ and $\{x\} \times (y-\delta , y+\delta)$ are subsets of $A$. prove that $A$ is lebesgue measurable.

a set like $A$ may be not an open set, like the below set:

[image]

Comment: It could possibly make it easier to answer the question if you provide more context: Where did you get this exercise? Are you sure that the statement is true? Do you know about Borel measurability?

Answer (score 0):

This is false. You can find a bijection from reals to reals whose graph $G$ is non measurable in plane. But the complement of $G$ is a $+$ set.

To construct such a function list all compact positive measure subsets of plane $\{K_{i} : i < 2^{\omega}\}$. Let $\{r_i : i < 2^{\omega}\}$ list all reals. Construct $f = \bigcup_{i < 2^{\omega}} f_i$ where

(1) $f_i$ is a partial injection from reals to reals with $|dom(f_i)| \leq max(|i|, \omega)$

(2) $\{r_j : j < i\}$ is contained in domain of $f_i$

(3) $\{r_j : j < i\}$ is contained in range of $f_i$

(4) The graph of $f_i$ meets $K_j$ for every $j < i$

At stage $i$, to satisfy (2), (3) simply add some appropriate pairs to $f$.   To satisfy (4), note that for some $x$ not in the current domain of $f$, the vertical section of $K_i$ at $x$, $(K_i)_x = \{y : (x, y) \in K_i\}$ has size continuum. Pick some unused $y$ in here and add $(x, y)$ to $f$.

Comment: That -1 is a trap. My answer is awesome in case you are wondering.

Comment: Yes, your comment and the **idea** of your answer *are* **awesome**. +1. But your answer would have been even more awesome if you have provided a (link to the) construction of such a bijection. Furthermore, you could have given an argument for the fact that the complement is a "$+$"-set. This would also have shown that we only need the function to be injective, not necessarily surjective.

Comment: @OohAah can you give me an example of such this function from reals to reals?

Comment: I added a construction for such a bijection.

Comment: @PhoemueX I left the details to the OP. It would have been a good learning experience for them.

Comment: There are as many compact sets than reals ? I thought there was much more...

Comment: @Xoff: At the first moment, it might appear this way. But since each compact set is closed and since closed sets are exactly the complements of open sets, it suffices to show that there (at most) continuum many open sets. But since each open set is a union of balls with rational radii around points with rational centers, it is not hard to see, that there are at most as many open sets as there are subsets of the class of all "rational balls". This amounts to exactly $2^\omega$ many.

Comment: @OohAah: I agree that one should not always spell out all details. But almost none of the people I know that would not know the answer to the posted question know enough about cardinalities and transfinite induction to **understand** your construction. Hence they know **much less** than is needed to come up with the construction on their own.

Comment: @PhoemueX Ok, I see your point.

Comment: @PhoemueX thank you for this nice explanation.