# A non-measurable set in the plane with no three points collinear

Tags: measure-theory, fubini-tonelli-theorems

The following is an exercise from Bruckner's Real Analysis:

> There is a set $E \subset \mathbb{R^2}$ such that $E$ meets every closed subset of
> $\mathbb{R^2}$ having positive Lebesgue measure, and no three points of $E$ are
> collinear. Show that such a set cannot be Lebesgue measurable.

There are a few discussions available on the Internet including [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1121531/nonmeasureable-subset-of-mathbbr2-such-that-no-three-points-are-collinea?rq=1) but none is understandable. An easy-to-understand detailed explanation would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you having trouble with the proof that such a set exists or with the proof that such a set is not Lebesgue measurable? (Or both?)

Comment: Can you link the other discussions on MSE?

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti : "with the proof that such a set is not Lebesgue measurable?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll prove that such a set is not measurable, as that is what OP is struggling with. To do this, I'll prove that $E$ has measure $0$ and infinite measure simultaneously if it is measurable.

1. If $E$ is measurable, then we can evaluate $\int_E1$ via Tonelli's theorem as $$\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{(x,y)\in E}1dydx$$Note that for any $x$, $\int_{(x,y)\in E}1dy=0$ since the set we are integrating over has at most $2$ points (otherwise we found $3$ collinear points.) Thus, $\int_E1=\mu(E)=0$.
2. If $E$ is measurable, since the Lebesgue measure is regular, $\mu(E)=\inf\{\mu(O)\mid E\subset O,\;O\text{ open}\}$. But, for any open set $O$ such that $E\subset O$, $C=\mathbb R^2\setminus O$ is closed, with $C\cap E=\varnothing$. Thus, $\mu(C)=0$, so $\mu(O)=\infty$. Thus, $\mu(E)=\infty$.

This establishes a contradiction.

Comment: Why $\mu(C)=0$?

Comment: Well, if $\mu(C)>0$, that's a closed set with positive measure, that $E$ has no points in.