# Measurability from knowledge of "slices"

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $(X,\mathcal{B},\mu)$ and $(Y,\mathcal{C},\nu)$ are standard measure spaces, so $X$ and $Y$ are Polish spaces and $\mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{C}$ are the Borel $\sigma$-algebras. Consider the product $X\times Y$. From the Fubini-Tonelli theorem it follows that if $E\subseteq X\times Y$ is measurable, then almost all slices $E_x$ and $E^y$ are measurable (in $Y$, resp. $X$). The converse is not always true, see for instance [Converse for Fubini-Tonelli's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1774046/converse-for-fubini-tonellis-theorem).

I was wondering, if you assume that all slices $E_x$ and $E^y$ are open, is that enough to imply that $E$ is measurable?

I would already be happy to just see if this is true or not for say the unit interval $[0,1]$ (in fact every standard measure space with non-atomic measure is isomorphic to $[0,1]$, so that's already fairly general). Also if there are other conditions that make it true, I would certainly be interested in knowing about them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a striking example constructed by Sierpinski (see https://eudml.org/doc/212592, but the paper is in french), which shows the following (quote from Folland's "Real Analysis"):

> Using the axiom of choice, but not the continuum hypothesis, Sierpinski has proved the existence of a Lebesgue nonmeasurable  subset of $\Bbb{R}^2$, whose intersection with any straight line contains at most two points.

Now, if you consider $E = M^c $ of this set, then each of the  slices  $E_x $ and $E^y $ is the complement of a finite set and thus open. But $E $ itself is not measurable.

Comment: Thanks! Je parle français, donc pas de problème.