Reference request: Measure of a preimage in a product with fibers of equal measure
I feel the following problem has most likely been studied before, but I did not find anything in the measure/probability theory books I have lying around. This seems to be a question studied in the context of product measures, because I could "show" this to hold by an overly naive exchanging order of integration argument. Can someone please give me a reference?
Let $(M,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a measure space, let $(S,\mathcal{C})$ be a measurable space, and let $(S\times M, \mathcal{B},\nu)$ be another measure space such that $\mathcal{C} \otimes \mathcal{A} \subseteq \mathcal B$ and $\mu = \nu \circ \pi^{-1}$. Here $\pi$ is the (necessarily measurable) projection onto the second factor, i.e. $\pi \colon S \times M \to M  , (a,x) \mapsto x$.
Further, let both $f\colon S \times M \to\mathbb{R}, (a,x) \mapsto f_a(x)$ and $f_a\colon M \to \mathbb{R}$ be measurable for every $a \in S$, and assume there exists a $y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that for all $a,a'\in S$ it holds that
$$\mu\left(f_a^{-1}(\lbrace y\rbrace)\right)=\mu\left(f_{a'}^{-1}(\lbrace y\rbrace)\right) \ .$$
Claim: For any $a \in S$ the following equality holds:
$$\nu \left(f^{-1}(\lbrace y\rbrace) \right)  = \mu\left(f_a^{-1}(\lbrace y\rbrace)\right) \ .$$
To see why this ought to hold, note that, if we set $A_a \equiv f_a^{-1}(\lbrace y\rbrace)$, then
$$f^{-1}(\lbrace y\rbrace) =\bigcup_{a' \in S} \lbrace a'\rbrace \times A_{a'} \ . $$
This may seem a bit obscure at first, but one can think of $\bigcup_{a' \in S} \lbrace a'\rbrace \times A_{a'}$ as a "strip" indexed by $a' \in S$ with "infinitesimal slices" $A_{a'}$ of equal length (i.e. a subbundle of a trivial bundle with fibers of equal measure). Then the above statement says that I can replace all slices by just a single one and still have the same area. This is also why I think this has been studied before.
EDIT1: The question was edited in light of Severin's comments (I retained the meaning of $\mathcal{B}$, so people can still follow). Also note that I am looking for a reference to a similar statement, I may be missing an assumption to get there (merely requiring that $\mu = \nu \circ \pi^{-1}$ may not be strong enough).
EDIT2+3: I adapted the language again. Again following Severin's comments, I added now that the "subbundle" of the trivial bundle $S \times M$ is defined as the preimage of a measurable function and I changed the title and the text accordingly. The right hand side in the last display equation is the set that caused all the measuability issues discussed in the comments; that this is now the preimage of some point under a measurable function should solve that issue. The question arose in the context of probability theory.

If $S$ is countable, then this might be fine. However, I'd expect measurability problems popping up if $S$ is not countable.

For example if $M=[0,1]=S$, $\mathcal{A}, \mathcal{B}$ the respective Borel-sigma algebras. You claim now that if $L\subseteq [0,1]^2$ is such that every slice is a null set, then $L$ is Borel-measurable. That is not really true (pick a rotated indicator function of your favourite non-Borel null set in $[0,1]$).

Now, if you are asking about subbundles, there should be no measurability issues (cover by charts and use the continuity of charts). Once you know the sets are measurable, you can use Tonelli to conclude. I suggest you add the precise statement you want for your bundles, then people can try to answer your actual question.

Thanks for the comments, I hope this fixes any measurability issues.

It was 2, but yes, you provided a $\nu$ for which the right hand side was $4$, so I was pointing out a contradiction to the assumptions. In other words, it was not a counterexample.

Yes, the original example was not a counter example. I modified it to what I originally intended. You may also look up “disintegration theorems” to find something you are looking for

Thanks for the comment, I will take a closer look at that.
One note though: This adapted example is still not a counterexample, because $2=\mu(\lbrace a \rbrace)=\nu(S \times \lbrace a \rbrace)$. For the Lebesgue measure, the right hand side is 0, so, again, this choice of $\nu$ does not work.

Again, the condition $\mu = \nu \circ \pi^{-1}$ needs to be satisfied; otherwise it doesn't work, of course.

@user510186 Your condition does not rule out my counterexample. The product of the Borel sigma algebras are actually equal to the Borel sigma algebra of the product.

@SeverinSchraven So you are saying that $\mathcal{B}$ needs to satisfy some "completion criterion" for the set to be measurable? If so, please, be my guest and suggest one.
Also, after Alex Ortiz's comment I looked a bit more at disintegration theorems and found this:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175862/disintegration-theorem-a-reference-needed
I looked at the book by Bogachew, but it is a bit much to disentangle tbh. But maybe it is of use to other people.

@user510186 Completeness is not saving you. We can play the same game for the product of the $1$dim Lebesgue measure (though it is more complicated) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2005413/measurability-from-knowledge-of-slices Same for the disintegration theorem, one needs to start with something measurable.

The measurability issue should be fixed now.
