# Interesting consequences of $2^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_2$?

Tags: set-theory

So reading some other questions here, I noticed that the continuum hypothesis $2^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_1$ has some strange consequences for analysis. The negation of the Axiom of Symmetry is one, as well as [this Fubini's theorem counterexample](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1774046/converse-for-fubini-tonellis-theorem).

Now, I also know that $2^{\aleph_0}$ can be just about any aleph number, but are there any interesting or counterintuitive consequences of it specifically being $\aleph_2$? What about the more generalized version of this hypothesis, $2^{\aleph_\alpha} = \aleph_{\alpha+2}$? Is that even consistent?

Comment: I have heard that the continuum hypothesis is equivalent to the uniqueness of the ultrapower $\mathbb{R}^\omega/U$ up to isomorphism.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know any interesting consequences of $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_2$ or related statements alone. However, there are reasonably natural principles which imply $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_2$ and also imply many interesting statements, my favorite being the **Proper Forcing Axiom** (PFA) and its variants; see [this paper](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~justin/Ftp/ICM.pdf) by Moore.

---

Meanwhile, the principle "For all $\alpha$, $2^{\aleph_\alpha}=\aleph_{\alpha+2}$" *is consistent (relative to large cardinals, **necessarily**)*, but that's far from obvious; see [this paper of Magidor and Woodin](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2944324), as well as [this Mathoverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/79920/failure-of-the-gch).

That said, again I don't know any interesting consequences from this alone. In general, my understanding is that simple arithmetic facts like these don't tend to have lots of interesting consequences on their own. *(Obviously when I say "simple" I'm referring to the form of the statement; as the results mentioned above indicate, "$\forall\alpha(2^{\aleph_\alpha}=\aleph_{\alpha+2})$" is extremely complicated once we really dive  intothings.)*

Comment: Wasn't there some paper on set theory in an AMS journal a few years ago arguing that $2^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_2$ was the "right" resolution of the CH problem philosophically in combo with a PFA variant? By a well-known guy. Woodin?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Woodin argued for $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_2$ previously - in [this survey](https://www.ams.org/notices/200107/fea-woodin.pdf) (maybe what you recall?) - but that now he favors CH being **true**, partly due to confidence in ["Ultimate $L$"](http://logic.harvard.edu/EFI_Woodin_StrongAxiomsOfInfinity.pdf) and partly due to [Sargsyan's refutation](https://ivv5hpp.uni-muenster.de/u/rds/sargsyan_thesis.pdf) of aspects of his argument against CH (see the end of, and the comments below, [this MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/25179/8133), and really that whole question is interesting).